# Error: Route.put() requires callback functions but got a [object String]

Tags: node.js

I am getting this issue while executing the code in eclipse and below is the my code.I have created only two methods get and put only. get() method is working fine put() is showing the error mesage.

```
.put('/:employeeId/update',function(req, res) {
        // Get our REST or form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
        var empName = req.body.empname;
        var empSalary = req.body.salary;
       var empId = req.params.employeeId;
       console.log("Emp Name::"+empName);
        //find the document by ID
        mongoose.model('Employee').findOne({"empid":empId}, function (err, employee) {
            //update it
            employee.update({
                empname : empName,
                empsalary : empSalary,
            }, function (err, empid) {
              if (err) {
                  res.send("There was a problem updating the information to the database: " + err);
              } 
              else {
                      //HTML responds by going back to the page or you can be fancy and create a new view that shows a success page.
                      res.format({
                          html: function(){
                               res.redirect("/blobs/" + employee.empid);
                         },
                         //JSON responds showing the updated values
                        json: function(){
                               res.json(employee);
                         }
                      });
               }
            })
        });
    });
```